# Local Spark talking to remote HDFS?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

I have a file in HDFS inside my HortonWorks HDP 2.3_1 VirtualBox VM.

If I go into the guest spark-shell and refer to the file thus, it works fine

val words=sc.textFile("hdfs:///tmp/people.txt") 
  words.count

However if I try to access it from a local Spark app on my Windows host, it doesn't work

```
 val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("My App") 
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf) 

  val words=sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:8020/tmp/people.txt") 
  words.count
```

Emits

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockMissingException: Could not obtain block: BP-452094660-10.0.2.15-1437494483194:blk_1073742905_2098 file=/tmp/people.txt
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.chooseDataNode(DFSInputStream.java:838)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:526)

The port 8020 is open, and if I choose the wrong file name, it will tell me

```
Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:8020/tmp/people.txt!!
```

localhost:8020 should be correct as the guest HDP VM hat NAT port tunneling to my host Windows box.

And I it's telling that if I give it the wrong name I get an appropriate exception

My pom has

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Am I doing something wrong? And what is the BlockMissingException trying to tell me?

Comment: Even if there is NAT..I think they are considered as separate machines and you should have proper DNS resolution to work. Try connecting using the ip or configure local DNS in windows and linux vm instance